# Sending secure wse headers via Soap in php5

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I am having a problem sending security wse headers to consume web services and already tried several dozens way of using this webservice from TargetProcess.com  and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

(http://demo.tpondemand.com/Services/ProjectService.asmx?wsdl)

Their example uses a really old version of Nusoap, however I am trying to do this using php5 built in SoapClient class.

I am stuck between receiving Bad Request errors or Unable to authenticate. So how can I send these headers?

This is what I have so far but doesn't work:

```
     $tp_header_part = '
      <wsa:Action>
        http://targetprocess.com/RetrieveAll
      </wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>
        urn:uuid:'.$this->getGuid().'
      </wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:To>http://medios.tpondemand.com/Services/ProjectService.asmx</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
          wsu:Id="SecurityToken-'.$this->getGuid().'">
        <wsse:Username>MYUSERNAME</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
          MYPASSWORD
        </wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>';


$soap_var_header = new SoapVar( $tp_header_part, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null );

$soap_header = new SoapHeader( 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext', 'Security', $soap_var_header );
$client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_header);
```

p.s The getGuid function simply generated a guid requiered per their documentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wondering if you were able to get this working? I am trying to connect with a .NET SOAP API in PHP and it's been a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

If the target server is written using .NET/ASP, it can be very fussy about getting "perfect" XML requests - for example, when using a namespace prefix, it is essential to include the declaration of the namespace in the XML as well.

I can see several examples of namespaces in your XML (wsa, wsse, SOAP-ENV), which do not appear to be delcared - and I'd be surprised if the PHP SoapClient was able to automatically populate them.  The only one you appear to have declared fully is 'wsse' = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext', through the initiation of your SoapHeader object.

If possible, put a packet sniffer (e.g. [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)) between the PHP and the target server to see exactly what is being sent and received - this can make it a lot easier to track errors, and figure out why the XML is being rejected.

I'd suggest 2 modifications to your initial code, which ought to make it "valid XML":

- wsa:Action - add `xmlns:wsa="<URL for definition of WSA>"`
- SoapHeader - I'm not sure, but since you've put the namespace URI here it might be necessary to include the namespace prefix on the Object name:

  ```
  $soap_header = new SoapHeader( 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext', 'wsse:Security', $soap_var_header );
  ```

Most important thing though is to find some way to get the exact HTTP conversation between the PHP Client and the target Server - and if you can also get a working example to compare and contrast, that usually makes life 100% easier!